# Sign of integer and binary AND check

Tags: go, binary-operators

If I'm right in C++ the LSB is the last bit and determines the sign of the integer. So for example in case of a 8 bit 1111 1111 will be -127 and 1111 1110 will be 127. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it's not related.

I would check fir the sign of the integer in Go, so I wrote the following:

```
func signCheck(n int8) {
    var sign int8 = 1<<7

    if n&sign == 1 {
        fmt.Printf("%d is odd - %b\n", n, n)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%d is even - %b\n", n, n)
    }
}
```

This will print out "constant 128 overflows int8", but that make sense because because there is only 7 bit used for determine a number. So I modified as follow:

```
func signCheck(n int8) {
    if n&1<<7 == 1 {
        fmt.Printf("%d is odd - %b\n", n, n)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%d is even - %b\n", n, n)
    }
}
```

In this case I don't have to say it's an int8 but I tested it with -127 and 127 and got the following prints:

```
-127 is even - -1111111
127 is even - 1111111
```

So in that case how should I check for the sign?
*go version go1.13.1 linux/amd64*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To represent negative integers, Go (and I believe C++ too like most languages) uses the [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) format and standard.

In 2's complement the highest bit (MSB) will be `1` if the number is negative, and `0` otherwise.

In Go you can't use a `0x80` typed constant having `int8` as its type, because that's outside of its valid range.

You may however convert `int8` to `uint8` "losslessly", and then you may do so.

Also, when you're masking the `0x80` bit, you have to compare the result to `0x80`, because `x & 0x80` can never result in `1`, only in `0` or `0x80`.

```
func signCheck(n int8) {
    if uint8(n)&0x80 == 0x80 {
        fmt.Printf("%d is negative - %b\n", n, n)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%d is non-negative - %b\n", n, n)
    }
}
```

Another option is to compare the masking result to `0`:

```
if uint8(n)&0x80 != 0 { }
```

Both solutions give the output (try them on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tnRmV9YDdcR)):

```
-127 is negative - -1111111
127 is non-negative - 1111111
```

Comment: Note that standard C allowed one's complement and sign-and-magnitude (see https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7095/why-did-ones-complement-decline-in-popularity). I'm not sure if C++ allows it and nobody really uses anything but twos' complement for integers these days anyway, although floating point is sign-and-magnitude.